# Get nested selector without classes nor id's

Tags: jquery, node.js, jquery-selectors, cheerio

i am trying to scrape a website and i don't know how to get the selectors i want.
I am using this function:

```
function scrapeData(urls) {
var data = [];
var urlPromises = urls.map(function(url) {
    return request(url).spread(function(response, html){
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
            var $ = cheerio.load(html);
            var elements = $('.IframePrincipal').toArray();
            // Items to scrape
            return elements.map(function(el, index){
                var title = $(el).find('h2').text().replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
                var stock = $('#FormASP > table:nth-child(4) > tbody > tr > td > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td.IframePrincipal > table > tbody > tr > td > table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(2) > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > td > table > tbody > tr > td').html();
                var price = parseFloat($(el).find('td:nth-child(1)').text().replace(/\€|,/g, '.'));
                // Push items into data array
                return {Title: title, Stock: stock, Price: price, date: date};
            });
        }
        else {
            return [];
        }
    }, function(error){
        console.log("Error");
        return [];
    });
});
return Promise.all(urlPromises).then(flatten);
}
```

Var title works like a charm.
Var Stock doesn't, its just the css path i copypasted, and var price its from a previous website, anyway i dont know hot to get it either. I am just getting "null".

This is an example of url to scrape :
[Site to scrape](http://www.diotronic.com/semiconductores/triacs-thyristores/thyristores_p_7.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i was looking inspectors path instead of real code one.